# Covert SQL to Laravel Query Builder

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm a beginner regarding Laravel Query Builder, can you guys help me convert this SQL to Query Builder

```
public function check_available_room(Request $request, $checkin_date)
{
    $available_rooms = DB::SELECT("SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT room_id FROM bookings WHERE '$checkin_date' BETWEEN checkin_date AND checkout_date)");
    
}
```

**Book model**

```php
function rooms() {
   return $this->belongsTo(Room::class, 'room_id');
}
```

**Room model**

```php
public function bookings() {
    return $this->hasMany(Booking::class);
}
```

Thank you so much

Comment: do you have a relation in place between Room::class and Booking::class? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have this in Booking model
function rooms()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Room::class, 'room_id');
    }`
`
Room model

`
public function bookings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Booking::class);
    }
`

Comment: Take habit to add any extra details to your question directly, anyway, the answer i provided should work perfectly with those relations

Comment: Yes, will do. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution if you have your models and relations in place

```
$availableRooms = Room::whereDoesntHave('bookings', function($bookingQuery) use ($checkin_date) {
    $bookingQuery->where('checkin_date', '<', $checkin_date)
    ->where('checkout_date', '>=', $checkin_date);
})->get();
```

Comment: I've encountered an error "Object of class Closure could not be converted to string"

Comment: @JamesRussel my bad, wrong method name, corrected it to `whereDoesntHave`. `doesntHave()` doesnt take a second parameter.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly, although I added "=" to the "<" now its "<=", thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
$unavailable_room_ids = Booking::where('checkin_date', '<', $checkin_date)
    ->where('checkout_date', '>=', $checkin_date)
    ->pluck('room_id')->get();

$available_rooms = Room::whereNotIn('id', $unavailable_room_ids)->get();
```

Comment: you can do it with a single query. Using two queries like you did might end up with errors if the number of value in $unavailable_room_ids returned is high enough.

Comment: You are correct about the relation, but I don't think MySQL and Laravel's IN Query limitations differ; its upper threshold is quite large.

Comment: it depends on the mysql server configuration but remember that IN query is converted to `in(?, ?, ?, ?.....)` so it uses that much placeholders. You can get the results with a single query either with the relations or with a join if no relation is in place.

Comment: Please bear in mind that related models are fetched with an IN query whatsoever, so it's basically the same thing. :)

Comment: That is for the eager loading (when you use `with()` method) but it is not true for exist queryes like when you use `whereHas()`. try it yourself, do a whereHas and a `toSql()` in the end.

Comment: You wouldn't want to *not* eager load those constraints in the event of having to deal with hundreds of ids as you mentioned.

Comment: Check my answer, there is no `IN` component to that query.